# Functional derivative of the functional $\int_{x_0}^{x_1} \left( y'^4(x) + e^{2y(x)} \right) \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

How to find functional derivative of the following functional?

$$J(y) = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \left( y'^4(x) + e^{2y(x)}  \right) \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functional derivative of a functional of the form

$$J(y) = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} L(x,y,y')\mathrm{d}x$$
is the LHR of the [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Euler.E2.80.93Lagrange_equation):
$$\frac{\delta J}{\delta y}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}$$

so, in your case:
$$\frac{\delta J}{\delta y}=2e^{2y}-4\frac{d}{dx}y'^3$$

Comment: It has a mistake. The correct answer is given by @Rodrigo de Azevedo. Btw, so fashionable.

Comment: What is the difference? Compute the derivative with respect to $x$ and you have the same result.

Comment: I'm very sorry. My fault.

Answer (score 2):

Using [SymPy](http://live.sympy.org) to compute the Euler-Lagrange equation:

```
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> y = Function('y')(x)
>>> L = (Derivative(y,x))**4 + exp(2*y)
>>> euler_equations(L,y,x)
                          2   2           
    2*y(x)      /d       \   d            
[2*e       - 12*|--(y(x))| *---(y(x)) = 0]
                \dx      /    2           
                            dx
```

Thus, the functional derivative is

$$2 e^{2 y} - 12 (y')^{2} y''$$